# Sum of nested objects

Tags: javascript, lodash

I want the sum price and I've used nested arr.reducers to solve it. I am just wondering if I should do it in a better way.

```
const cart = [
  {
    name: ...,
    price: 400,
    options: [
      { id: 1, name: ..., price: 200 },
      { id: 2, name: ..., price: 200 }
    ]
  },
  { name: ..., price: 100, options: [] }
];


const sum = products =>
  products.reduce((acc, product) => {
    const options = product.options.reduce(
      (acc, option) => acc + option.price,
      0
    );
    return acc + product.price + options;
  }, 0);
```

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Ok thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take an iterative and recursive approach by using `options` for nested items.

```js
const
    getTotal = (total, { price, options }) =>
        total + price + (options?.reduce(getTotal, 0) || 0),
    cart = [{ name: '', price: 400, options: [{ id: 1, name: '', price: 200 }, { id: 2, name: '', price: 200 }] }, { name: '', price: 100, options: [] }],
    total = cart.reduce(getTotal, 0);
    

console.log(total);
```

Comment: Thanks! Learnt something new.

Answer (score 1):

You can use nested lodash `_.sumBy()` calls:

```js
const cart = [{ name: '', price: 400, options: [{ id: 1, name: '', price: 200 }, { id: 2, name: '', price: 200 }] }, { name: '', price: 100, options: [] }];

const total = _.sumBy(cart, o => o.price + _.sumBy(o.options, 'price'));    

console.log(total);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
```